# Clr dll .net control

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, dll, clr

I need to dynamic loading some .NET control from DLL in runtime from C# winforms host project.

for example:

1.dll contrains control1

2.dll contrains control2

3.dll contrains control3

host app may load any of this dll-s, get controls from dll and put it on self form.

I tried:

```
__declspec(dllexport) TestCLRPlugin::Properties ^ GetControl()
{
    return gcnew TestCLRPlugin::Properties();
}
```

but, clrcall methods can't be exported from dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) methods and then you can use reflection to get the method/class/etc you want from the assembly.  There are pretty good examples if you follow the MSDN link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you're looking for, but you may want to read up on reflection, which makes this pretty easy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx

Sorry if you're already familiar or that doesn't help.